# React render component even though state doesnt change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  console.log("rendered...")
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const setFourValue = () => {
    setCount(4);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", columnGap: ".25rem" }}
      >
        <button onClick={increaseCount}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={setFourValue}>Set 4</button>
        <span>{count}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I try to figure out when and how component render. Situation that i try to is i increased count to 4 and now my count value is 4. But i click to 'Set 4' button my count value is still 4 but still component re-rendered. After that if click again 'Set 4' button component doesn't re-render. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Barry's answer, when you set the count to`4` the first time with `setFourValue` after increasing it to `4` with `increaseCount`, it actually isn't 4. Console log the count and you'll see that it's actually `3` even though it displays `4` on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In React, components will only re-render if a `state` or `prop` in the component change.

Setting `4` to `4` is not a change.

React is smart enough to not re-render unnecessarily.

Comment: But if click 'Set 4 ' button after increasing count value up to four with the 'Increase' button state didn't change but component re-render ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your `increaseCount` function. When you are updating a state property using its previous value, the callback argument must be used. This is due to the asynchronous nature of state updates. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

```
const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount((count) => (count + 1));
};
```

It could probably be the reason why the `count` was 3 instead of 4 as said by @Tim van Dam.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here are correct in explaining how the callback pattern of setState should be preferred when the updated state value depends on the previous state value. But one part of the question is still pending

> But i click to 'Set 4' button my count value is still 4 but still component re-rendered.

I created this [`sandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-kate-qbu0ql?file=/src/App.js:0-626) and this indeed happens.

If we do `setCount(4)` from `increaseCount` and then from `setFourValue`, both trigger a rerender.

[The answer is here though](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html?fbclid=IwAR3rAXffa8s5dx1DSJgf_KNnvm9Roz39goXCinDpD3QJ1zl76OeKds7pMTs#bailing-out-of-a-dispatch)

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.

And React indeed does not go deeper into the tree, which you can check by uncommenting `<Child>`. It is not going deeper into the tree as `<Child>` will not rerender, even if `<App>` does.